# ¿Cómo obtener mi clave SHA1 sin mi contraseña del almacén de claves (keystore)?

Tags: keystore

Estoy intetando ejecutar el siguiente comando para encontrar mi clave SHA1:

```
PS C:\Users\ltomi\StudioProjects\prueba> keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\ltomi\.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepasswd
```

pero al ejecutarla me pide la "Contraseña del almacén de claves". He leído que la contraseña por defecto es "changeit", pero al ponerla me dice que la contraseña es incorrecta:

> error de herramienta de claves: java.io.IOException: keystore password
> was incorrect java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect
> at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
>
> ```
>     at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
>
>     at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
>
>     at java.security.KeyStore.load(Unknown Source)
>
>     at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Unknown Source)
>
>     at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Unknown Source)
>
>     at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Unknown Source)
> ```
>
> Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: failed to decrypt
> safe contents entry: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final
> block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used
> during decryption.
> ... 7 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agregué este código al final de la línea y funcionó sin pedirme la contraseña:

```
android -keypass android
```

Quedo de la siguiente forma:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\rojas\.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```